# Graphics3D flickers in Mathematica 10 and Linux

Tags: graphics, version-10, linux

**Note:** Fixed in version 10.0.2.  Bug present in version 10.0.0.

---

In the official Mathematica version 10.0, I get a very weird behavior when I try to rotate a 3d graphics

> [image]

The moment I click on the graphics to drag it, it seems like it zooms the whole graphics for a fraction of a second. I'm here on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with Gnome 3.4.2 and an NVidia GeForce GTX 590 with NVidia driver.

I have reported this to Wolfram, but do others experience this and is there any known solution to the problem?

Comment: That looks distracting.  Does `RotationAction -> "Fit"` or `RotationAction -> "Clip"` have any effect on this behavior?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nope. Exactly the same flicker. Btw, per suggestion of Olek I updated the NVidia driver to the newest version. Still the same behavior.

Comment: "do others experience this?" I've been using Mathematica 10 on Fedora 20 (64-bit) with Gnome 3.10 and an nVidia GeForce GTX 480 with nVidia drivers and I have not seen this problem.

Comment: All I can add is that I see no flickering in v10.0 on CentOS 7.0, but I have Intel graphics: so I'd suggest logging into KDE, XFCE or whatever and see if Gnome is at fault.  I plan on testing v10.0 on my nVidia 780 Gnome desktop soon...

Comment: I'm seeing this on nvidia graphics, although there's only one flicker before the rotation starts, and then it works normally.

Comment: @Ruslan For me, the bug is gone. There is a small flicker when I release the 3D Graphics from the rotation and if *snaps* into its final form (with antialiasing), but otherwise, it works smooth.